# Detecting a line with open curly brackets

Tags: string, parsing, tcl

I am parsing a tcl file line line by line and searching for lines with open curly braces so that I can merge them with the next line and read them.
I am struggling to get a single regex to do this. My concern is lines with with a closing } which can be skipped.

Example:
MATCH: test_command -switch1 {

NO MATCH: single_command

NO MATCH: test_tcl -switch2 {arg1 }

Please help with the regex to get the result. I tried this:

```
% set a "test_command -swithc1 {bye }"
test_command -swithc1 {bye }
% regexp "{" $a match
1
#0 is expected
```

This is not my intention. I want match only for lines with open curly brace

```
% set b "test_command -swithc1 {hi"
test_command -swithc1 {hi
% regexp "{" $a match
1
#1 was expected
```

I'm looking for a regex that will give 0 for the $a and 1 for $b

Comment: Tcl regular expressions aren't really a good match for this. You might be able to do something in a dialect that supports recursive matching, like perl/pcre...

Comment: Or use a real parser. See https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/parsetcl for one tcl parser written in tcl. Or https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/A+Tcl+parser+in+Tcl or https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Naive+Tcl+parser (And a few others on the wiki)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using a regular expression for that; there's a Tcl command *specifically* for this sort of thing: `info complete`. Here's how to use it:

```
set accumulator ""
while {![eof $inputChannel]} {
    # Note well: you *must* add the newline
    append accumulator [gets $inputChannel] "\n"
    if {[info complete $accumulator]} {
        handleCompleteChunk $accumulator
        set accumulator ""
    }
}
```

This handles various types of bracket matching and the intricacies of backslash sequences, but *just* to check whether the “line” is complete. (It's also the core of how Tcl's REPL works, except that uses the Tcl C API equivalents.)

Comment: Note that this doesn't just produce the answer for a single line; it does the whole grouping lines together thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a couple "lookarounds", one to say "I see a left bracket" and one to say "I don't see a right bracket":

```
(?!.*\})(?=.*\{)
```

https://regex101.com/r/p8bbsF/1/

Comment: Always have to keep in mind the dialect of regular expression being used; that site doesn't include many common and uncommon ones ([tcl REs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), unfortunately, fall into the latter these days). Luckily, they *do* support positive and negative lookaheads using that syntax.

Comment: Thanks, This actually works in tcl. But, I am encountering more bugs/issues with this approach, and would use the existing parsetcl or tcl parser in the comments.